# How to send Username/Password and a Cookie using stream_context_create()

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to get the HTML code from a remote site, which creates different HTML output based on the cookie being sent.

So I am trying to send username/password and a cookie with stream_context_create() function.

It works without the $cookie in the header, but I get the wrong HTML.

With the $cookie I get a warning:

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.myURL.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in simple_html_dom.php on line 78

I think, I just do not know the syntax. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT)
{
    $usernamepw = "username:password";
    $cookie     = "skipPostLogin=1";
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($usernamepw) . $cookie, 
            'timeout' => 60
        )
    ));
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $defaultBRText);
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
    if (empty($contents))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follow:

```
    function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT)
{
    $usernamepw = "username:password";
    $cookie     = "skipPostLogin=1";

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($usernamepw),
        'Cookie: ' . $cookie
    );

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => $headers,
            'timeout' => 60
        )
    ));
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $defaultBRText);
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
    if (empty($contents))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
```